# Neo4j Queries cannot be run directly on a session with an open transaction; either run from within the transaction or use a different session

Tags: javascript, neo4jclient, neo4j-javascript

I am new to using Neo4J and I came across this error, I am closing and opening the sessions, however, I am receiving this error.

```
const session = driver.session({ database });
await session.run(`CREATE (u:USER} {name:"Test Demo"} ) return u`)
```

I use the above code in the signup function. I'm using session.close() at the finally block.
It is working fine for single requests. when I hit API from 2 devices simultaneously one API gets the error "Queries cannot be run directly on a session with an open transaction; either run from within the transaction or use a different session."

If it is possible to handle multiple requests at same time, tell me how to achieve that. Thanks